# О выражении "лезть в бутылку"

Tags: фразеология

Честно говоря, до конца не пойму, в каких случаях употребляется выражение "лезть в бутылку", потому что не могу понять его этимологии. Мне сразу представляется что-то, связанное с джиннами))))))))

Comment: Прибираясь весной на даче после зимы обнаружила в бутылке дохлую мышь ....забралась внутрь,а вылезти не смогла ....я так и вспомнила выражение"не лезь в бутылку"..Чем не объяснение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Джины залезающие в бутылку - это как раз одна из основных версий происхождения данного выражения. Есть ещё предположение, что данная фраза пошла от блатного наименования одной из петербуржских тюрем, но то что прозвище у тюрьмы давно, а выражение впервые встречается лишь во второй половине XX века, версии противоречит. Отсутствие фразеологизма в других языках, дискредитирует гипотезу заимствования. В целом же, вопрос происхождения этой фразы ещё, до конца, ещё не выяснен.

Значение у "лезть в бутылку" следующее: *кипятиться по пустякам, устраивать скандал на ровном месте или по крайне незначительному поводу*. Например, если вам случайно наступили на ногу в автобусе, то не стоит лезть в бутылку и на весь салон выяснять отношения с обидчиком. Лучше, просто, спокойно принять извинения и ехать дальше.

Comment: А мне нравится версия франц. заимствования. У французов это звучало как "не лезь в бутылку"  http://lifecity.com.ua/?id=5960&l=knowledge&mod=view  Слова «Не лезь в бутылку!» стали в ходу при королевском дворе. Так обращались к человеку, желая предостеречь его от совершения необдуманных поступков и неприятностей. Если король распалялся гневом на одного из своих фаворитов, нечаянно рассердившего его,  ему говорили: «Он больше никогда не полезет в бутылку, Ваше Величество!». Только так можно было заслужить прощение. И значение связано как раз с предупреждением "Не наживай себе неприятностей"

Comment: что-то ссылка не работает. Ещё раз:   http://lifecity.com.ua/?id=5960&l=knowledge&mod=view

Comment: Людмила, но то что так можно было заслужить прощения - это же совсем не *версия* появления.  
Точно так же, совергенно непонятна фраза 
>>Королевский служащий произносил при этом короткую команду: «Не лезь в бутылку!».    
(по ВаАшей ссылке).  

Она никак не объясняется ситуацией.

Comment: @Людмила, мне тоже версия нравится, но учитывая, что во французском такого выражения нет, да и в русском оно фиксируется, только во 2-й половине ХХ века, когда французский уже практически не влиял, версия выглядит сомнительно.

Comment: Мне самому больше нравится версия, что выражение появилось в связи с популяризацией в середине века статуэток типа "корабль в бутылке". Тогда первоначальное значение - усложнять простое. Однако упоминаний такой версии не обнаружил, также как и свидетельств возрастания популярности, поэтому в ответе о ней и не упоминал.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не нравится объяснение такого "родного" выражения влиянием какой-то чужой культуры, будь то арабские джины или погреба французских монархов. Хотя последнее даже более правдоподобно (якобы собаки чувствовали испорченное вино в закрытых емкостях, т.е. королевским сомелье не надо было **лезть в бутылку**).
Еще меньше нравится версия о какой-то питерской тюрьме, по форме напоминающей бутылку. Но только потому, что в подобных случаях всегда точно известно, о каком реальном объекте идет речь.

Есть вот такая информация:

«В 1828 году на территории Новой Голландии по проекту архитектора военного ведомства А. Е. Штауберта была построена Морская тюрьма. Сам архитектор во время проектирования назвал строение "Башней". За время её существования обиходное название видоизменялось, в конце концов в народе её стали называть "Бутылка"» (http://www.walkspb.ru/zd/nov_gol.html).

Но она недостоверна:
http://photos.wikimapia.org/p/00/03/08/46/79_full.jpg

Какая башня, какая бутылка?

Мне все-таки кажется, что значение самодостаточно. У бутылки узкое горло - и залезть туда ну никак не возможно.

//=====

Да, вот еще  что. В Интернете есть и версии о том, что выражение может быть связано с алкоголем: дескать не лезь в бутылку может означать "не напивайся, веди себя как пьяный". Объяснение логически хорошее, но малореальное в плане ситуационном. Кому и как такое могли сказать в якобы исходном значении?

Answer (score 1):

А как же разум человека и русский язык. Не лезь в бутылку, а то залезешь и вылезти (быстро) уже не сможешь.. подумай о своих действиях ибо могут они нанести вред самому же себе..также (думаю )можно коснуться темы алкоголя..для человека не контролирующего свои действия после принятия горячительных напитков.